# mysql does not know the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

1. `stud`
2. `sec`

s# and pname are fields.

I want to create a view of this query manually.

I used an inner join for this query, but mysql had this problem with it:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'stud.s' in 'on clause'
```

My query:

```
CREATE VIEW 
  vw_name 
AS
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  stud
INNER JOIN 
  sec 
ON 
  stud.s# = sec.s#
WHERE 
  pname = 'sara';
```

Comment: 1) You sure you are using mysql? 2) Can you provide ``SHOW CREATE TABLE`` of *stud* and *sec*?

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use '#' in a fieldname. Maybe you have to escape it in your query?

Comment: Don't use `#` in your column names.  `snum` or `sno` will save you hours of future heartache.

Comment: I used another field without #,but I saw this: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'pname' again.I think it has a problem with the field that is repeated.I dont khow what should I do with Duplicate column

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, and other object names are known as identifiers. An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).

Therefore, like Mike W stated you should quote `stud.s#`.

Comment: Or else one should avoid using special symbols in column names, to make things simpler.

Comment: I used another field without #,but I saw this: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'pname' again.I think it has a problem with the field that is repeated.I dont khow what should I do with Duplicate column